# Does Google index the new domain names as "keyword"? (i.e.: dance.club as "dance club")

Tags: seo, keywords, top-level-domains

I have some doubts about how Google rates new domains.

The idea is using the name of the product (using ".name" as domain example).

Is `product.name` better (or at least not worse) than `productname.com`, `product-name.com` or `productname.biz`?

Comment: Domain names have little effect on your score. Nevertheless still curious for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has repeatedly said that the gTLD does not affect ranking:

> Overall, our systems treat new gTLDs like other gTLDs (like .com &
>   .org). Keywords in a TLD do not give any advantage or disadvantage in
>   search.

[Source](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/07/googles-handling-of-new-top-level.html)

Answer (score 1):

Between what google say and what guts (experience) say...

I didn’t do an academic work on this, but I published 3 or 4 websites using international TLDs (Hebrew & Arabic) without real content at first (CMS install success page). I used Google search (lazy to switch keyboard and type) to browse and already after 2 or 3 days I was surprised to find them already on the first page somewhere near the 5 top results, websites that were published since a while with much more cleaner SEO (but english TLD). The last one was 2 weeks ago.

May be it help only with non-english TLDs ?